# HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream converts &lt; instead of < etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api

HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream converts < instead of < etc.
I am using an HttpWebRequest to retrieve XML data from a web service. Web API

My content type is:
request.ContentType = "application/json";

The problem is, when I retrieve the text, everything inside the Envelope, the response, is converted. So <> are < and >, etc..

How do I retrieve the data, and retain the less than / greater than symbols for valid XML?

thanks!

replace method converts all special charatcters inbetween of xml < > envelop which i dont want

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
//request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";

request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
request.Method = HttpVerb;
request.Accept = "application/xml";
if (ObjData != null)
{
    var Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjData);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        sw.Write(Serialized);
    }
}
else
{
    request.ContentLength = 0;
}
HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized || httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError || httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable)
    {
        strResponse = httpWebResponse.StatusDescription;
    }
    else if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        strResponse = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", httpWebResponse.StatusCode);
    }
    else
    {
        strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();// this line creating the wrong xml
        strResponse = XMLDecode(strResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: `So <> are < and >, etc..` I don't understand what that means.

Comment: it is converting < chart into &lt, which i dont want

Comment: &lt;Results success="1" api="1" version="7.0"&gt;   

should come as 

<Results success="1" api="1" version="7.0">

Answer (score 1):

this 3 lines of code resolved my issue:

strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();// here it is creating a problem converting a < chart with &lt etc

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();// this 3 line solved the issue of xml

xmlDocument.LoadXml(strResponse);

strResponse = xmlDocument.InnerText;